# How to Bind Publisher Message to Custom class in my Receiver with out @Payload

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-amqp

In my application i am publishing Message from one of FileProcess service(which will process CSV file and convert that to CSVPojo and publish to queue by using **RabbitTemplate**.

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("spring-boot-rabbitmq-BulkSolve.async_BulkSolve_Msg", "BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue", pojo);
```

I have another service BusinessProcess service that have to Listen to this queue and get messages and do some business process on those messages.To do this we intended to do this using SpringBatch, so i created a job which will listen queue and process. The trigger point for the job is as below.

```
@EnableRabbit
```

public class Eventscheduler {

```
@Autowired
Job csvJob;

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

//@Scheduled(cron="0 */2 * ? * *")
@RabbitListener(queues ="BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue")
public void trigger(){
    Reader.batchstatus=false;
    Map<String,JobParameter> maps= new HashMap<String,JobParameter>();

    maps.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(maps);
    JobExecution execution=null;
    try {
        //JobLauncher jobLauncher = new JobLauncher();
         execution=jobLauncher.run(csvJob, jobParameters);
    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JobRestartException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("JOB Executed:" + execution.getStatus());

}
```

}

so my job will trigger when there is a msg published to this Queue. And after my job triggered in my job iam getting exception in my reader. In reader i am getting below exception.

```
org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name [com.comcast.FileProcess.Pojo.CSVPojo]
```

Below is my Reader class which i used to read message as receiver.

```
@Component
public class Reader extends AmqpItemReader<List<RequestPojo>>{

    @Autowired
     @Qualifier("rabbitTemplate")
     private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public static boolean batchstatus;

    private List<RequestPojo> reqList = new ArrayList<RequestPojo>();

/*  @Autowired
    private SimpleMessageListenerContainer messagelistener;*/

    public Reader(AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        super(rabbitTemplate);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    List<RequestPojo> msgList = new ArrayList<RequestPojo>();
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<RequestPojo> read() {



        if(!batchstatus){
        RequestPojo msg=(RequestPojo)rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert("BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue");

            //return (List<RequestPojo>) rabbitTemplate.receive();
        System.out.println("I am inside Reader" );
        msgList.add((RequestPojo) msg);

        //Object result = rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert();

        batchstatus=true;

        return  msgList;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here Consumer is Getting the Pojo class with its pacakge name  from publisher.
I am able to consume Messages by using @Payload below is my code using which successfully consumed messages(below is that code) but i want to consume messages by using RabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert("QueueName") Which i showed in my Reader class.

```
/*Below code sucesfully consumed messages from receiver side using @Payload*/
@RabbitHandler
    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = "simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory", queues ="BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue")
    public void subscribeToRequestQueue(@Payload RequestPojo sampleRequestMessage, Message message) throws InterruptedException {

System.out.println(sampleRequestMessage.toString());
}
```

Can any one help on this to resolve my error to consume published messages from Receiver using **RabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert("QueueName")**

As per your suggestion i have made some configuration changes as below for Jackson2JsonMessageConverter to bind the message to my custom class **RequestPojo** as per below but it still not bind the message to my custom class. Can you please suggest me what i am doing wrong here and suggest me what to do to make it work.

```
 @Bean
        public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
            template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
            return template;
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
            return jsonCustomMessageConverter();
        }

        @Bean
        public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonCustomMessageConverter() {
            Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
            jsonConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper());
            return jsonConverter;

        }
        @Bean
        public DefaultClassMapper classMapper() {
            DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
            Map<String, Class<?>> idClassMapping = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
            idClassMapping.put("RequestPojo", RequestPojo.class);
           // idClassMapping.put("bar", Bar.class);
            classMapper.setIdClassMapping(idClassMapping);
            return classMapper;
        }
```

Changed as per your suggestion but getting below error .

```
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.comcast.BusinessProcess.Pojos.RequestPojo] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[230], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=BulkSolve_SummaryrequestQueue, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, amqp_receivedExchange=spring-boot-rabbitmq-BulkSolve_summary.async_BulkSolve_Msg, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=BulkSolve_SummaryrequestQueue, amqp_redelivered=false, id=d79db57c-3cd4-d104-a343-9373215400b8, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-sYwuWA5pmN07gnEUTO-p6A, contentType=application/json, __TypeId__=com.comcast.FileProcess.Pojo.CSVPojo, timestamp=1535661077865}]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:142) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:112) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:107) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:126) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Below is my RabbitConfiguration class.

```
@Configuration("asyncRPCConfig")
@EnableScheduling
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitMqConfiguration {

public static String replyQueue;

    public static String directExchange;

    public static String requestRoutingKey;

    public static String replyRoutingKey;

    //public static final int threads=3;

    /*@Bean
    public ExecutorService executorService(){
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    }*/

    /*@Bean
    public CsvPublisher csvPublisher(){
        return new CsvPublisher();
    }
    @Bean
    public ExcelPublisher excelPublisher(){

        return new ExcelPublisher();
    }*/
    /*@Bean
    public GeneralQueuePublisher generalQueuePublisher(){
        return new GeneralQueuePublisher();
    }
    */
    /*@Bean
    public SummaryQueuePublisher summaryQueuePublisher(){
        return new SummaryQueuePublisher();
    }*/
    /*@Bean
    public Subscriber subscriber(){
        return new Subscriber();
    }*/
    /*@Bean
    public Subscriber1 subscriber1(){
        return new Subscriber1();
    }
    @Bean
    public Subscriber2 subscriber2(){
        return new Subscriber2();
    }
    @Bean
    public RestClient restClient(){
        return new RestClient();
    }*/
    /*@Bean
    public SubscriberGeneralQueue1 SubscriberGeneralQueue1(){
        return new SubscriberGeneralQueue1();
    }*/
    /*@Bean
    public SubscriberSummaryQueue1 SubscriberSummaryQueue1(){
        return new SubscriberSummaryQueue1();
    }*/
    @Bean
    public Eventscheduler Eventscheduler(){
        return new Eventscheduler();
    }
     @Bean
        public Executor taskExecutor() {
            return Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                                          SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
            configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
            return factory;
        }

       /* @Bean
        public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory_Summary(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                                          SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
            configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
            return factory;
        }*/



        @Bean
        public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
            template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
            return template;
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
            return jsonCustomMessageConverter();
        }

        @Bean
        public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonCustomMessageConverter() {
            Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
            jsonConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper());
            return jsonConverter;

        }
        @Bean
        public DefaultClassMapper classMapper() {
            DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
            Map<String, Class<?>> idClassMapping = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
            idClassMapping.put("com.comcast.FileProcess.Pojo.CSVPojo", RequestPojo.class);
           // idClassMapping.put("bar", Bar.class);
            classMapper.setIdClassMapping(idClassMapping);
            return classMapper;
        }

        @Bean
        public Queue replyQueueRPC() {
            return new Queue("BulkSolve_GeneralreplyQueue");
        }

       @Bean
        public Queue requestQueueRPC() {
            return new Queue("BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue");
        }

        /*below are the newly added method for two other queues*/
        @Bean
        public Queue summaryreplyQueueRPC() {
            return new Queue("BulkSolve_SummaryreplyQueue");
        }

        @Bean
        public Queue summaryrequestQueueRPC() {
            return new Queue("BulkSolve_SummaryrequestQueue");
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleMessageListenerContainer rpcGeneralReplyMessageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(replyQueueRPC());
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
            //simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter1);
            return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
        }
        @Bean
        public SimpleMessageListenerContainer rpcSummaryReplyMessageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(summaryreplyQueueRPC());
            //simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter2);
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
            return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
        }

       /* @Bean
        @Qualifier("listenerAdapter1")
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter1(SubscriberGeneralQueue1 generalReceiver) {
            return new MessageListenerAdapter(generalReceiver, "receivegeneralQueueMessage");
        }*/

      /*  @Bean
        @Qualifier("listenerAdapter2")
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter2(SubscriberSummaryQueue1 summaryReceiver) {
            return new MessageListenerAdapter(summaryReceiver, "receivesummaryQueueMessage");
        }*/


       @Bean
        public RequestPojo requestPojo(){
        return new RequestPojo();
        }
       /* @Bean
        @Qualifier("asyncGeneralRabbitTemplate")
        public AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncGeneralRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

            AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncGeneralRabbitTemplate = new AsyncRabbitTemplate(rabbitTemplate(connectionFactory),
                            rpcGeneralReplyMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory),
                            "spring-boot-rabbitmq-BulkSolve.async_BulkSolve_Msg" + "/" + "BulkSolve_GeneralreplyQueue");

            AsyncRabbitTemplate at = new AsyncRabbitTemplate(connectionFactory, "spring-boot-rabbitmq-examples.async_rpc", "rpc_request", "replyQueueRPC","replyQueueRPC");
            return asyncGeneralRabbitTemplate;
        }

        template defined for other 2 queues
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("asyncSummaryRabbitTemplate")
        public AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncSummaryRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

            AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncSummaryRabbitTemplate = new AsyncRabbitTemplate(rabbitTemplate(connectionFactory),
                    rpcSummaryReplyMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory),
                            "spring-boot-rabbitmq-BulkSolve_summary.async_BulkSolve_Msg" + "/" + "BulkSolve_SummaryreplyQueue");

            AsyncRabbitTemplate at = new AsyncRabbitTemplate(connectionFactory, "spring-boot-rabbitmq-examples.async_rpc", "rpc_request", "replyQueueRPC","replyQueueRPC");
            return asyncSummaryRabbitTemplate;
        }*/

        @Bean
        public DirectExchange directExchange() {
            return new DirectExchange("spring-boot-rabbitmq-BulkSolve.async_BulkSolve_Msg");
        }
      //Added new exchange
        @Bean
        public DirectExchange directExchange1() {
            return new DirectExchange("spring-boot-rabbitmq-BulkSolve_summary.async_BulkSolve_Msg");
        }
        @Bean
        public List<Binding> bindings() {
            return Arrays.asList(
                            BindingBuilder.bind(requestQueueRPC()).to(directExchange()).with("BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue"),
                            BindingBuilder.bind(replyQueueRPC()).to(directExchange()).with("BulkSolve_GeneralreplyQueue"),
                            BindingBuilder.bind(summaryrequestQueueRPC()).to(directExchange1()).with("BulkSolve_SummaryrequestQueue"),
                            BindingBuilder.bind(summaryreplyQueueRPC()).to(directExchange1()).with("BulkSolve_SummaryreplyQueue")
                            );


        }

}
```

//Below is my Reader class

```
@Component
public class Reader extends AmqpItemReader<List<RequestPojo>>{

    @Autowired
     @Qualifier("rabbitTemplate")
     private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public static boolean batchstatus;

    private List<RequestPojo> reqList = new ArrayList<RequestPojo>();

/*  @Autowired
    private SimpleMessageListenerContainer messagelistener;*/

    public Reader(AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        super(rabbitTemplate);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    List<RequestPojo> msgList = new ArrayList<RequestPojo>();
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<RequestPojo> read() {



        if(!batchstatus){
        RequestPojo msg=(RequestPojo)rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert("BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue" );
        //rabbitTemplate.receiveandco
            //return (List<RequestPojo>) rabbitTemplate.receive();

        System.out.println("I am inside Reader" + msg);
        msgList.add(msg);

        //Object result = rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert();

        batchstatus=true;

        return  msgList;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Below is my Trigger point code which trigger Job when message is there in queue.

```
@EnableRabbit
public class Eventscheduler {

    @Autowired
    Job csvJob;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    //@Scheduled(cron="0 */2 * ? * *")
    @RabbitListener(queues ="BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue")
    public void trigger(){
        Reader.batchstatus=false;
        Map<String,JobParameter> maps= new HashMap<String,JobParameter>();

        maps.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(maps);
        JobExecution execution=null;
        try {
            //JobLauncher jobLauncher = new JobLauncher();
             execution=jobLauncher.run(csvJob, jobParameters);
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobRestartException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("JOB Executed:" + execution.getStatus());

    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note CSVPojo from  my publisher and RequestPojo from my Receiver side are having same properties. I am unable to cast to RequestPojo from RabbitTemplate.recieveandcovert("quename") .

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed there is slight difference between `subscribeToRequestQueue(@Payload RequestPojo sampleRequestMessage)` and `rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert("BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue")`. And right, that one is exactly that `@Payload RequestPojo` which is missed in the raw `receiveAndConvert()`. Therefore when this method is performed there is no target type to consult for the expected conversion. This way we just fallback to whatever we have in the incoming message. In your case that is a `__TypeId__` header with the source type from the producer `com.comcast.FileProcess.Pojo.CSVPojo`.

If you really would like to the enforce the conversion on the consumer side into the `RequestPojo`, you need to consider to use an overloaded `receiveAndConvert` variant:

```
/**
 * Receive a message if there is one from a specific queue and convert it to a Java
 * object. Returns immediately, possibly with a null value. Requires a
 * {@link org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SmartMessageConverter}.
 *
 * @param queueName the name of the queue to poll
 * @param type the type to convert to.
 * @param <T> the type.
 * @return a message or null if there is none waiting
 * @throws AmqpException if there is a problem
 * @since 2.0
 */
<T> T receiveAndConvert(String queueName, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> type) throws AmqpException;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I guess i have to write this overloaded method in Consumer side right? I am confused as you mentioned to write this method  in Producer.

Comment: unfortunately  in RabbitTemplate class i am unable to find the Overloaded method receiveAndCovert(String queueName, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> type). Is it available in latest version?

Comment: Yes, sorry I really meant on the consumer side: `RabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(String queueName, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> type)`.

Comment: See Javadocs of that method: `@since 2.0`. Right, it's not available in the previous version, so you would need to implement some custom `MessageConverter` or consider to configure a proper type mapping on the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`

Comment: Thanks Bilan for your response. I will upgrade my version to get benefit by that overloaded method.

Comment: well. If i want to follow the approach to configure a proper type mapping on Jackson2JsonMessageConverter is below code i changed in my RabbitConfiguration  as below is it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179132/discussion-between-user3853393-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: Sorry, I don't chat here on SO. That's fully inconvenient and I have some work to do, so our conversion is definitely going to be with some delays. You can just edit your question and comment here about that. I'll come back to your whenever I can. Thanks for understanding. The type mapping info is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/_reference.html#_converting_to_a_message_2

Comment: Hi Bilian, i have edited my thread and added the configuration changes to make Message to Bind to my Custom Pojo object in my receiver , but not working. Can you please help me to identify the issue what causing it not to work.

Comment: Your `__TypeId__` is `com.comcast.FileProcess.Pojo.CSVPojo`, so mapping must be like this: ` idClassMapping.put("com.comcast.FileProcess.Pojo.CSVPojo", RequestPojo.class);`

Comment: Thanks Bilan. Changed as per your suggestion but got some exception while processing added error stack trace in main thread, can you please suggest me what went wrong.

Comment: `Cannot convert from` - what is the cause though? I don't think that this is the end of the stack trace in logs...

Comment: Wait, according that error the story is not about `receiveAndConvert()`: it is a part of `@RabbitListener`. Sounds like a different story with its own details

Comment: Yes You are correct Bilian. The issue is due to some other thing in my configuration. I have resolved that issue and able to run the service. Now my service is able to listen the queue to receive messages but here the issue is my Receiver is getting Null from the queue ,It is not getting the object published from Producer side. I have edited my Thread and added RabbitConfiguration class and Reader class from where i am receiving message. Can you please tell me what make my code not to get Null value instead of the original message.

Comment: That's correct: if there is no messages in the queue the `receive()` returns `null`. The default `receiveTimeout` in the `RabbitTemplate` is `0`, so `doReceiveNoWait(queueName)`

Comment: Hi Bilian. There is a message in the queue. Producer published the message to queue. I am also able to see that on Rabbit Console. And more over I wrote the Job trigger point when there is a message then only execute reader which is working fine(After pushing message it is showing on  rabbit console and Triggering the Spring batch job which internally read message).

Comment: OK. So, you need to debug that `receiveAndConvert()` from the IDE. If there is no any errors, I can't help from here. Well, I can help to debug it for you, but only if you share very simple project on GitHub with simple instruction how to reproduce. Otherwise I'm useless. Sorry

Comment: Edited main thread and added that trigger point code. Which triggers job when message is there in queue.

Comment: Why do you need manually pull messages from the queue when you have already that `@RabbitListener(queues ="BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue")`? Just make an appropriate `RequestPojo` argument in that method and proceed with your logic? To be honest there is no message anymore after that `@RabbitListener` - it is just pulled already by the Listener Container, so your manual `receiveAndConvert()` against the same queue has already nothing to pull. I'm confused...

Comment: Thanks Bilan that make sense thanks for your explanation. Here my use case is i am using springBatch frame work to run job  here i want to trigger the job  when Producer push message to queue for that purpose only i am using @Rabbitlistener class as Trigger point of job, is there any other way to trigger the job based on new message push from producer  instead of reading it? so that job will be triggered and inside job reader i will read messages manually for further processing. Just like event listening in Java script, please suggest me is there any way to do that?

Comment: Well, you can trigger the job by the message received via that `RabbitListener` method and the message can become a job parameters. I don’t understand why you try to overcomplicate the purpose of the listener...

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have to see how to pass arguments to Itemreader as the JobLauncher is taking care of running Job the Job will run the ItemReader read() method.

Comment: Is there any way in my Listener to get all messages as list ? I  mean i can get message by using @Payload inside listener but if i want all the messages(suppose 100 in queue)  at a time and want to populate to a List for further processing. Is there any method? to achieve this?

Comment: No, there is no. That's not what is the *streaming* about. We can't know how many messages are in the queue.